# Break into Kennedy Space Center and enter the rocket

Tags: rockets

In my story, some kind of vigilenties are chasing a hitman in Florida after she tried to kill them.

They are in Titusville just before the first manned flight for Mars takes off from Kennedy Space Center, the hitman sees them and crosses the Indian River to the island.

Spoiler, I'd like them to end up in the rocket.

My question is: **how is it possible to cross NASA security (which I can imagine is huge) and enter a rocket just before launching without anyone to notice ?**

I already explored some tracks, like stealing an astronaut suit, but not sure this is quite realistic, this would end up adding even more security layers to go through.

(Not sure also about the tags for this kind of questions)

**Edit:** Okay, I understood it seems a bit tricky. Let's assume they all manage to enter KSC alive and undetected, would it be realistic to say that they break in the hangar and manage to enter the rocket during last minute modifications, few hours before lauching, and hide inside ?

Comment: Don't put answers in comments, thanks.

Comment: Having an employee's opinion would probably be most accurate. If you should fail to get an answer here, you could perhaps try [the Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't see how is that **world**building. It's a very specific story. I know that many questions around are close to the edge, but to me that one is really on the wrong side of it.

Comment: @ALambentEye not sure if they'll be willing to teach me how to steal their rockets, but it's worth trying haha

Comment: @JulesR As long as you don't tell them you're a Russian spy, terrorist or flat-worlder and provide them with all the information you've ever known and loved, you should be fine. Perhaps.

Comment: Quoting XKCD: I got in touch with a friend of mine who works at a research reactor, and asked him what he thought would happen to you if you tried to swim in their radiation containment pool.
“In our reactor?” He thought about it for a moment. “You’d die pretty quickly, before reaching the water, from gunshot wounds.”

Comment: So one problem with your hiding for a few hours scenario is that the vehicle assembly building (VAB) is some distance from the launch towers and getting the craft from the VAB to Tower is 5 hour drive over the 3.5 mile distance.  The craft is then on the launch pad for a total of 43 hours, not including an additional 12 hours of holds built into countdown and that's if there is no launch conditions that may force a scrub to the next available window... which could be weeks away (this is weather dependent).  The Astronauts board at T-2.5 hours to launch+

Comment: + and since the fuel to weight ratio is very high for a space launch, it would be rather cramped... you wouldn't get much of a hiding spot for an additional person without spilling stuff onto the floor... which would get spotted.  There would be plenty of time for a lockdown to search for your wayward hitman... depending on how close to first mission to mars you are, there would be a massive media presence.  Also, it's a three mile radius exclusion zone from the launch tower.

Comment: @hszmv thanks for the informations, that is interesting

Comment: @JulesR:  Yeah.  Wikipedia has an outline of a Space Shuttle launch countdown and what events happen and when.  One other thing to note is that, due to operations in micro-gravity environments, the orbiter (the part of the Shuttle that looks like a plane) is meticulously cleaned and access is restricted to minimize contaminants such as dead skin and stray hairs from getting into the area.

Answer (score 9):

It's unlikely at best. If you get off of the heavily monitored roads, KSC is also the world's largest alligator preserve. There's lots of critters with big appetites and teeth to match. If you get past them, you have to climb the Gantry, several stories high, covered in ice, under spotlights, with live 24x7 monitoring.

See [image from lower tower the day of the Challenger disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger_disaster#/media/File:Icicles_on_the_Launch_Tower_-_GPN-2000-001348.jpg)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is the Gantry "covered in ice" given the latitude of KSC?

Comment: They are filling the LOX and LH tanks for a few days prior to launch.  The high volume and low temperature causes dangerous icing on the gantry. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger_disaster#/media/File:Icicles_on_the_Launch_Tower_-_GPN-2000-001348.jpg

Comment: +1 thanks for the extra info

Comment: +1 for the Alligators.  They are a very efficient security system in Florida.  Nearby Orlando International Airport doesn't have fences around the restricted areas... they have moats, which are just as efficient.  Floridians assume that any body of water that is not man made pool or the ocean has Alligators in it... and even then, wildlife control is not unfamiliar with calls about Gators relaxing in the former...

Comment: Indeed, friends of mine from Florida assume that any body of water larger than a soda spill has a gator, and even then they look twice for the little ones.

Comment: Its probably a bad sign when i read KSC, and think Kerbal instead of Kennedy...

Comment: @hszmv Are alligators really that effective? I imagine alligators being a more effective deterrent than an actual form of defence, though I must admit I have had no practical experience concerning the subject.

Comment: A full grown bull can and will swallow a grown man whole. Floridians don't go jogging at twilight near any bodies of water.

Comment: @ALambentEye:  Most of the time, Alligators are not aggressive towards humans and don't hunt them (unlike Nile Crocodiles, which do hunt humans) however, this is because most people who live in Alligator areas do not go near natural bodies of water.  Alligators are ambush predators, and will attack anything in or near a body of water, and the waters in FL are very murky, so it could mistake humans for other animals.  American Alligators bite force is second only to the Salt Water Crocodile and can easily sever limbs and even with quick medical intervention, deadly infections can result.

Comment: @ALambentEye:  They're deadly from both ends too... the tail muscles are the more powerful than the jaw muscles (which once shut, can be held shut unassisted by human hand).   The reason that human death rate by Alligator attacks is that on average, people who live close to them know well enough to stay away from their habitats and they are rather slow on land.